# Как в горизонтальном меню вместо маркеров списка вставить изображение?

Tags: меню, html

Не пойму, как вставить изображение. У меня горизонтальное меню высотой 50 px, сделал изображение, которое хочу поставить вместо маркера списка, высота изображения тоже 50 px.

Код страницы:

```css
.menu{
    background-image: url(images/fon_menu.jpg);
    height: 50px;
}

li {
    float: left;
    list-style-image: url(images/kn_cl.png);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="sotrud.html">Сотрудники</a></li>
        <li><a href="docum.html">Документы</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">Новости</a></li>
        <li><a href="photo.html">Фотоальбом</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Если в `li` пишу `display: inline` или `inline-block`, то маркеры и изображения вообще не отображаются, исчезают.

С тем кодом, который есть сейчас, всё работает, но изображение смещает текст ссылки. Таким образом вместо маркера получается поставить только изображение такой высоты, какую высоту имеет текст ссылки (20 px). Если высота больше, сдвигается текст.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7fBc3/ так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо list-style-image лучше используйте обычный background. С его помощью можно гибко настроить позицию изображения, чего не получится в случае с list-style-image

http://jsfiddle.net/8fV3X/